# Reading SubRip file in Python, getting � where é is expected

Tags: python, unicode, python-unicode

The string is a spanish string: Am�rica

It should be an ê (tilde) but for some reason I am getting � instead.

I have looked at using .decode and .encode also the unicode() methods in Python but nothing is giving me the output that I desire.

What is the best way to convert this character into the correct "e" with tilde?

Does this even make sense? Can I convert from � to ê ??

I ran a hexdump on the file containing the Am�rica and this is what i found:

```
(env)bvh331-apvpsv01:active admin$ hexdump test.txt 
0000000 41 6d ef bf bd 72 69 63 61 0a                  
000000a
```

I also ran a file -I to get the char_set:

```
alexdaro@hplive-us163783-la-silo01 Desktop $ file -I tmp.es.srt
tmp.es.srt: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

Comment: The first thing we need to know is the encoding the file is in. If you don't know this, then this question comes down to guesswork.

Comment: ...if you wanted to at least make the guesses informed ones, you could include hexdump output so we'd know which specific bytes were being used to encode the character in question.

Comment: 1. `ê` has a circumflex, not a tilde. 2. The circumflex isn't used in Spanish. 3. That word doesn't need a tilde - it should be `América`.

Comment: ...the other question, of course, is whether your *terminal* is correctly rendering what the Python interpreter is emitting. Your code could be 100% perfect, but if Python were writing out UTF-8 and your terminal were rendering Windows-1252, then your terminal couldn't correctly print the characters emitted regardless.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 - yes thank you for the clarification. I ran mediainfo on the file and this is what it displays: \n (env)bvh331-apvpsv01:active admin$ mediainfo tmp.es.srt 
General
Complete name                            : tmp.es.srt
Format                                   : SubRip
File size                                : 23.0 KiB

Text
Format                                   : SubRip
Compression mode                         : Lossless

Comment: Have you change page encoding to **UTF-8**??

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - hexdump displays this : (env)bvh331-apvpsv01:active admin$ hexdump test.txt 
0000000 41 6d ef bf bd 72 69 63 61 0a                  
000000a

Comment: You should have specified that this was a SubRip file explicitly in your question (not a "text file"). The format specifies an encoding (specifically, CP-1252)

Comment: That said, this looks to me like your file is just badly encoded -- this string isn't valid CP-1252 either -- unless there's a BOM at the top of the original you've discarded.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy - can you explain a bit more? If that format requires CP-1252 encoding.... how can i convert in python?

Comment: BTW, `file -I` doesn't do any kind of special magic -- it just guesses. We can probably guess better than it does. :)

Comment: Proper UTF-8 encoding for `América` (forward accent, not circumflex or tilde) would be `41 6D C3 A9 72 69 63 61`.

Comment: Thanks @LeeDanielCrocker - can you also explain a bit, how would i use that proper encoding to convert via python?

Comment: @AlexDaro, you'd modify the input file to have the content Lee gave you, not the content it already has. Which is to say: Assuming that it's supposed to be UTF-8 (and start with a BOM), it's simply *wrong*. (If it's wrong because someone did a hack to make some specific piece of hardware with a non-UTF8-compliant font print the right character, that doesn't make it less wrong).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ok, thank you.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - SubRip (.srt) files are just text. The extension is just so the media player can detect the file as a subtitle file. That said, these files are often automatically generated via graphical analysis of a video stream. This text recognition process can result in lots of errors, such as incorrect accents, lowercase L instead of uppercase i, and so on.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, a text file with a format that defines rules about its encoding is distinct from "a text file" with no rules defined. Which is to say: Yes, all SubRip files are text files, but not all text files are SubRip files, so knowing that we're working with a subset categorically is helpful information.

Answer (score 1):

The sequence "ef bf bd" is UTF-8 for U+FFFD (REPLACEMENT CHARACTER), i.e., a special code that is shown as "�", as mentioned in your question. Therefor, something (Python?) must have replaced the original char with this code. So your terminal appears to be okay.

The 'é' character U+00E9 (LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE) in UTF-8 would read "c3 a9" instead.

It is conceivable that your original subtitle might be encoded as CP1252, where the 'e' is represented by code 0xe9. Since the next byte is 0x72 ('r'), your parser might have interpreted the 0xe9 as an incomplete UTF-8 sequence and therefor replaced the "e9" with "ef bf bd" (REPLACEMENT CHARACTER).

Answer (score 0):

Per [the wikipedia article on SubRip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubRip#Text_encoding):

> The SubRip `.srt` file format really only supports the Microsoft Windows text encoding default of CP-1252 (commonly, but incorrectly, referred to as ANSI). A Unicode byte order mark can be added to support any Unicode encoding with UTF-8 being preferred for its compatibility with CP-1252. However, a number of embedded hardware-based players only have support for non-Unicode fonts due to the licensing costs associated with the commercial fonts used.

However, this string does not render as desired in CP-1252:

```
>>> print '\x41\x6d\xef\xbf\xbd\x72\x69\x63\x61'.decode('cp1252')
Amï¿½rica
```

Thus, presumably you excerpted this content from a larger file which started with a BOM (byte order marker) indicating its encoding, but discarded that BOM (and thus encoding information). As an alternate theory, the original file (and, thus, software that generated and read it) may simply have been noncompliant with the SubRip standard, or have been generated for use with hardware with a non-Unicode fontset.